# Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 Upgrade Failed

Tags: 13.04, upgrade, vmware, 13.10

I have a VMware virtual machine running Ubuntu 13.04, and yesterday tried to upgrade to 13.10. The install got about half way through and then everything seemed to just freeze completely.

I left it going overnight to see if it was just taking a while, but this morning it was still stuck. Nothing would respond at all so I had to just murder it and force a restart with VMware.

Now, when I try and boot the virtual machine back up, it just hangs forever at the Ubuntu splash screen.

How can I see what's *actually* going on behind the scenes rather than just seeing the splash screen sit there?

Answer (score 0):

```
mount -o remount,rw /
dpkg --configure -a
mount -o remount,ro/
sync
reboot
```

I couldn't actually perform the final remount/sync as the drive was busy so just went for the reboot and hoped for the best. Everything started up and I'm running 13.10 without any issues.

The `--configure` took about 20mins so a bit of patience here

Comment: Where can I actually put these commands? I'm not sure how to even get to a terminal from the splash screen.